# Read a val defined in build.sbt from a command

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm writing a command in a project/MyCommand.scala file.
I need to access to a val defined in my build.sbt such as:

```
val scala3 = "3.1.3"
```

I do not know how to get it from the state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The common approach for that would be to define the `val`s (or `def`s) you need to access within the project directory, e.g. like this:

```
// in project/ProjectConstants.scala
object ProjectConstants {
  val Scala3Version = "3.1.3"
}
```

Then you could access that from both your `build.sbt` and from other code that resides in the project directory:

```
// works in both build.sbt and project/MyCommand.scala:
val scala3 = ProjectConstants.Scala3Version
```

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a solution but because I do not want to change the definitions in the existing build.sbt file of the open-source project I'm contributing to, I would rather find a way to read it from the state if possible.

Comment: To my knowledge, that is not possible. What you could access from within `project/MyCommand.scala` would be the (values of the) actual sbt settings, e.g.: `def scalaVersionFromSbt: String = sbt.Keys.scalaVersion.value`. Depending on what you want to achieve, maybe that could do for a workaround?

Comment: Thanks. I've arrived at the same conclusion and this is what I did.